# Redirect all trailing slashes globally in express

Tags: node.js, express, disqus

I am using Node.js and Express and I have the following routing :

```
app.get('/', function(req,res){
    locals.date = new Date().toLocaleDateString();

    res.render('home.ejs', locals);
});

function lessonsRouter (req, res, next)
{
    var lesson = req.params.lesson;
    res.render('lessons/' + lesson + '.ejs', locals_lessons);
}

app.get('/lessons/:lesson*', lessonsRouter);


function viewsRouter (req, res, next)
{
    var controllerName = req.params.controllerName;
    res.render(controllerName + '.ejs', locals_lessons);
}
app.get('/:controllerName', viewsRouter);
```

I have a [Disqus](http://disqus.com/) widget on my lessons pages and I have noticed a strange behavior that when going to `myapp.com/lessons` and `myapp.com/lessons/` I get two different pages (on of them had a comment I previously added in Disqus and the other one doesn't have a comment).

Is there a way to "canonize" all of my urls to be without trailing slashes ? I have tried to add the `strict routing` flag to express but the results were the same

Thanks

Comment: What version of express are you using? In 3.x, the default behavior (without turning `strict routing` on) makes `/foo` and `/foo/` appear the same to the router. Given that the page is rendering either way, my first guess is that this is a browser caching issue, but without knowing anything more about disqus, I can't be sure.

Comment: @DavidWeldon express 3. This might be `Disqus` seeing it as two different addresses. In any case, how should I redirect any address with trailing `/` to an address without ? This way, even if the user enters `/` in the browser it will get redirect to the right path

Comment: If you know the issue will always be isolated to one specific route, I'd add the redirect to that specific route handler. If not, I'd go with a middleware solution like Tolga gave below.

Comment: "strict routing: Enable strict routing, by default "/foo" and "/foo/" are treated the same by the router"
`app.set('strict routing', true);`
 ~ src: http://expressjs.com/api.html#app-settings

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Try adding a middleware for that;

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const test = /\?[^]*\//.test(req.url);
  if (req.url.substr(-1) === '/' && req.url.length > 1 && !test)
    res.redirect(301, req.url.slice(0, -1));
  else
    next();
});
```

Comment: This works. I prefer `req.url.slice(0, -1)` to `req.url.substring(0, req.url.length-1)`, but that's just a matter of style.

Comment: I'm still learning express middleware, stuff are becoming more clear, where should i put this code ?  I tried to put it straight after `app.configure` definition but it didn't catch

Comment: You can put that in anywhere before the `app.use(app.router)`, if you send the whole app configuration i can tell you more specifically, cheers.

Comment: @TolgaAkyüz I suspect you meant `res.redirect` instead of `req.redirect` ?

Comment: Also, I am getting a redirect loop when accessing root url `myapp.com` so maybe you can change the condition to `if(req.url.substr(-1) == '/' && req.url.length > 1)`

Comment: Yes, you are right, i was in a hurry, updated the answer, cheers.

Comment: Note that with this middleware the redirection doesn't work if there is anything after the slash. For example `http://example.com/lessons/?` won't be redirected even though `http://example.com/lessons/` will.

Comment: req.path is the expressjs property. req.url is inherited from node's http module. can also use `req.path[req.path.length-1] === '/'`

Comment: This only works for GET requests. In case you wish to redirect POST requests check for req.method and do an ajax request manually.

Comment: I would add method as well in case of a POST so that the POST data is carried over to the new URL: `let method = (req.method === 'POST') ? 307 : 301;  res.redirect(method, url);`

Comment: This won't work in a Next.js environment with requests like e.g. `http://localhost:3000/_next/on-demand-entries-ping?page=/`. This example completely misses any query param possibilities

Comment: Fails if there are query params

Answer (score 105):

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13443359/638546) by [Tolga Akyüz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1271840/tolga-akyuz) is inspiring but doesn't work if there is any characters after the slash. For example `http://example.com/api/?q=a` is redirected to `http://example.com/api` instead of `http://example.com/api?q=a`.

Here is an improved version of the proposed middleware that fixes the problem by adding the original query to the end of the redirect destination URL. The version also has a few safety features described in the update notes.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (req.path.slice(-1) === '/' && req.path.length > 1) {
    const query = req.url.slice(req.path.length)
    const safepath = req.path.slice(0, -1).replace(/\/+/g, '/')
    res.redirect(301, safepath + query)
  } else {
    next()
  }
})
```

**Update 2016:** As noted by [jamesk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442377/redirect-all-trailing-slashes-gloablly-in-express/15773824?noredirect=1#comment65975609_15773824) and stated in [RFC 1738](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1617074/638546), the trailing slash can only be omitted when there is nothing after the domain. Therefore, `http://example.com?q=a` is an invalid URL where `http://example.com/?q=a` is a valid one. In such case, no redirection should be done. Fortunately, the expression `req.path.length > 1` takes care of that. For example, given the URL `http://example.com/?q=a`, the path `req.path` equals to `/` and thus the redirection is avoided.

**Update 2021:** As discovered by [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442377/redirect-all-trailing-slashes-globally-in-express/15773824#comment122560025_15773824), a double slash `//` in the beginning of the path causes a dangerous redirection. For example the URL `http://example.com//evil.example/` creates a redirect to `//evil.example` that is interpreted as `http://evil.example` or `https://evil.example` by the victim's browser. Also, noted by [Van Quyet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442377/redirect-all-trailing-slashes-globally-in-express/15773824#comment97837154_15773824), there can be multiple trailing slashes that should be handled gracefully. Due to these findings, I added a line that safeguards the path by replacing all consequent slashes by a single `/`. I trust the performance overhead caused by the safeguard to be negligible because [the regexp literals are only compiled once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814009/how-often-does-javascript-recompile-regex-literals-in-functions). Additionally, the code syntax was updated to ES6.

Comment: I wonder how many people upvote Tolga's answer, run it for a few days, and then come back here when they realize this is missing.

Comment: Note this practice diverges from the format prescribed by RFC 1738: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1617074/5352503

Comment: @jamesk I updated the answer regarding the issue you pointed out. Fortunately, the middleware I proposed already handles it (see the note I added). I guess the confusion was caused by my poor url examples. The urls are now replaced with correct ones, thanks to you.

Comment: the format prescribed by RFC1738 have been overruled by other RFC (2396 and 3986) and by the URL Standard.
it is valid for an url to be of the form `http://example.com?q=a`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42193734/6205646

Comment: If we have URL: `http://example.com/abc/xyz/////` (more than one slash), we should not redirect it. I suggest to edit the condition to:
`(req.path.substr(-1) === '/' && req.path.substr(-2, 1) !== '/' && req.path.length > 1)`

Comment: This code is dangerous. It potentially creates an open redirect. For example if we make the request `http://example.com//evil.com/` (note the double slash at start of path and trailing slash) this will redirect to `//evil.com` which is interpreted as a protocol-relative link to evil.com

Comment: @Matt Thanks for discovering this hazard! I reviewed the answer and added a line with notes that prevents such malicious redirection. Let me know if you find any problems with this approach.

Comment: @AkseliPalén thanks for the edit! Is a pretty subtle bug. While investigating this I found a few major sites which were vulnerable to this issue, I already disclosed it to them :)

Answer (score 28):

The connect-slashes middleware was designed specifically for this need:
https://npmjs.org/package/connect-slashes

Install it with:

`$ npm install connect-slashes`

Read the full documentation:
https://github.com/avinoamr/connect-slashes

Comment: This is the preferred solution as it supports connect middleware and modularity

Comment: Thanks! Works well with Express v4 as well.

Answer (score 11):

I'm adding this answer because I had too many issues with other solutions.

```
/**
 * @param {express.Request} req
 * @param {express.Response} res
 * @param {express.NextFunction} next
 * @return {void}
 */
function checkTrailingSlash(req, res, next) {
  const trailingSlashUrl = req.baseUrl + req.url;
  if (req.originalUrl !== trailingSlashUrl) {
    res.redirect(301, trailingSlashUrl);
  } else {
    next();
  }
}

router.use(checkTrailingSlash);
```

This will translate:

```
/page ==> /page/
/page?query=value ==> /page/?query=value
```

Answer (score 7):

One liner:

```
router.get('\\S+\/$', function (req, res) {
  return res.redirect(301, req.path.slice(0, -1) + req.url.slice(req.path.length));
});
```

This will only catch the url's that need to be redirected, and ignore the others.

Example results:

```
/         ==> /
/a        ==> /a
/a/       ==> /a
/a/b      ==> /a/b
/a/b/     ==> /a/b
/a/b/?c=d ==> /a/b?c=d
```

Comment: would it be better to use `router.all'?

Answer (score 0):

The answers above will work in a lot of cases but GET vars can encounter issues and if you were to put that inside another express middleware its reliance on `req.path` will cause a problem and its reliance on `req.url` can also have unwanted side effects.
If you're looking for a tighter solution this will do the trick:

```
// Redirect non trailing slash to trailing slash
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    // Find the query string
    var qsi = req.originalUrl.indexOf('?');
    // Get the path
    var path = req.originalUrl;
    if(qsi > -1) path = path.substr(0, qsi);
    // Continue if the path is good or it's a static resource
    if(path.substr(-1) === '/' || ~path.indexOf('.')) return next();
    // Save just the query string
    var qs = '';
    if(qsi > -1) qs = req.originalUrl.substr(qsi);
    // Save redirect path
    var redirect = path + '/' + qs;
    // Redirect client
    res.redirect(301, redirect);

    console.log('301 redirected ' + req.originalUrl + ' to ' + redirect);
});
```

It's always happy with GET variables and won't break if you were to put it inside middleware.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * @param {express.Request} req
 * @param {express.Response} res
 * @param {express.NextFunction} next
 * @return {void}
 */
function checkTrailingSlash(req, res, next) {
    if (req.path.slice(req.path.length-1) !== '/') {
        res.redirect(301, req.path + '/' + req.url.slice(req.path.length));
    } else {
        next();
    }
}
  
app.use(checkTrailingSlash);
```

Example results:

```
/         ==> /
/a        ==> /a/
/a/       ==> /a/
/a/b      ==> /a/b/
/a/b/     ==> /a/b/
/a/b?c=d  ==> /a/b/?c=d
/a/b/?c=d ==> /a/b/?c=d
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use [fastify](https://github.com/fastify/fastify) to deal with your routes, you can try setting Fastify's ignoreTrailingSlash option to true.

```
const fastify = require('fastify')({
  ignoreTrailingSlash: true
})
```