# Rewrite url path using node.js

Tags: node.js, express

Is it possible to rewrite the URL path using node.js?(I'm also using Express 3.0)

I've tried something like this:

```
req.url = 'foo';
```

But the url continues the same

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Sure, just add a middleware function to modify it. For example:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.url.slice(-1) === '/') {
    req.url = req.url.slice(0, -1);
  }
  next();
});
```

This function removes the trailing slash from all incoming request URLs. Note that in order for this to work, you will need to place it before the call to `app.use(app.router)`.

Comment: I think it is working fine, but the path on the browser continues the same... Is it possible to rewrite the URL on the user browser too or just using res.redirect ?

Comment: If you want to modify the URL in the browser, I think you need to redirect the user. See the answer and comments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442377/redirect-all-trailing-slashes-gloablly-in-express/).

Comment: In Express 4 (and maybe earlier), this no longer works. The `Request` instance defines the `req` property as not `writable`.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder could you add an answer showing how to do this in more modern versions? I haven't been using express for a while so I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Turns out I can't read. For some reason when I skimmed over this question I read `req.path` not `req.url`. `req.url` is a property of `Http.IncomingMessage` so it can be set. Your original answer was correct. My apologies!

Comment: @BaileyParker What did you end up doing since `req.url` is no longer writable?

Comment: Specifically on removing end slashes, I don't think this solution will work if the URL has a query string that needs to be preserved. For that use-case, consider checking [`req.path`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.path) instead and reconstructing the URL using the modified path + query string.

Answer (score 2):

A good idea should be to update the `path` too. My method suggestions:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("request", req.originalUrl);
    const removeOnRoutes = '/not-wanted-route-part';
    req.originalUrl = req.originalUrl.replace(removeOnRoutes,'');
    req.path = req.path.replace(removeOnRoutes,'');
    return next();
});
```

By this way `/not-wanted-route-part/users` will became `/users`

Comment: in express@4.18.2 i get the following TypeError: Cannot set property path of #<IncomingMessage> which has only a getter

Answer (score 1):

you need override some properties of req (IncomingMessage in NodeJs):

- url
- path
- search
- query

2

```
function changeUrl(req, url) {
    const parsedUrl = new URL(url);
    req.url = url;
    req.originalUrl = url;
    req.path = parsedUrl.pathname;
    req.search = parsedUrl.search;
    req._parsedUrl = parsedUrl;
    const query = {};
    for(const entry of parsedUrl.searchParams) {
        query[entry[0]] = entry[1];
    }
    req.query = query;
}
```