# How do I do URL rewriting in Express JS 4

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to do URL rewriting in Express JS 4. Everything I read says that I should be able to overwrite the request.url property in middleware. The two existing Node modules that do rewrite use this method. However, when I try to do this:

```
app.use('/foo', function(req, res){
    var old_url = req.url;
    req.url = '/bar';

    console.log('foo: ' + old_url + ' -> ' + req.url);
});

app.get('/bar', function(req, res) {
    console.log('bar: ' + req.url);
});
```

it just doesn't work.

One note that might help: it appears that `req.url` above always is `/` regardless of the actual URL used. Did Express 4 change how the URL is maintained, and not update their documentation? How do I accomplish URL rewriting in Express 4?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want processing to continue after your change, you have to call `next()` in your middleware to keep the processing going on to other handlers.

```
app.use('/foo', function(req, res, next){
    var old_url = req.url;
    req.url = '/bar';

    console.log('foo: ' + old_url + ' -> ' + req.url);
    next();
});
```

The [doc for `req.originalUrl`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.originalUrl) says this:

> This property is much like req.url; however, it retains the original
>   request URL, allowing you to rewrite req.url freely for internal
>   routing purposes. For example, the “mounting” feature of app.use()
>   will rewrite req.url to strip the mount point.

Which certainly implies that you can change req.url to change the routing.

---

Related answer:[Rewrite url path using node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446030/rewrite-url-path-using-node-js)

Comment: Thanks for the help. There seemed to be two issues: one, that I didn't call next(), and two, that I didn't realize that `use('/foo', ...)` would pull the `/foo` off of the request.url.

Comment: You can also create a completely separate router and mount it. Like: `controller.js`: `var router = require('express').Router; router.get('/ur', handle);, router.post('/foo', handle);router.use('/bar', handle);`   
Then in the `app.js`: `var ctrl = require('./controller'); app.use('/top-level-url', ctrl);`

Answer (score 2):

Rewriting req.url doesn't work with app.use(...) for some reason.
(Express 4.17.1)

Use app.get(...) instead:

```
// this doesn't work
app.use('/foo', function(req, res, next){
  req.url = '/bar';
  next()
});

// this works
app.get('/foo', function(req, res, next){
  req.url = '/bar';
  next()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use routers, the best solution is to use

```
req.url = '/new-url/';
app.handle(req, res, next);
```

See more on this [gist](https://gist.github.com/ramonfritsch/06893c1c561d670687a9aee3bbc4e9c7)