# Serve static files from same dir as rendered file express

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following middleware for static files defined in express:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use('/lessons', express.static(__dirname + '/lessons', { redirect : false }));
```

Inside lessons folder I have a couple of lesson folders

```
lessons
|-- lesson01
|-- lesson02
.
.
.
```

Inside every lesson folder there's a `lesson.md` file that I render. This file has references to images in the same lesson folder. I want to be able to just use for example `img01.png` inside the markdown file to reference the image, but express expects the image to be found in `/lessons/img01.png` and not in `/lessons/lesson01/img01.png`.

Using `./img01.png` as a reference to the image in the markdown file didn't help either.

Any idea on how yo tell express to look in the same directory for the static file ?

Thanks

Edit :

A little more info,

The route to get the lesson file is :

```
app.get('/lessons/:name', function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.controller = 'lessons';
    var name = req.params.name;
    var lesson = lessons[name];
    if (!lesson) {
      return next();
    }
    lesson.path = 'lessons/' + name;
    lesson.file = lesson.path + '/' + name + '.md';
    markdown(lesson.file, function(result, err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      lesson.body = result;
      res.locals.lesson = lesson;
      res.render('lesson');
    });
});
```

Also, I am using middleware called [connect-slashes](https://github.com/avinoamr/connect-slashes) to remove the slash from the end of each URL. (As result of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442377/redirect-all-trailing-slashes-gloablly-in-express))

```
var slashes = require('connect-slashes');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use('/lessons', express.static(__dirname + '/lessons', { redirect : false }));
// add middleware to remove trailing slash in urls
app.use(slashes(false));
```

Comment: How do you access the rendered `md` files? I assume you render them to HTML, do you have a separate route for that?

Comment: @robertklep I render the `md` files on the fly through the `/lessons/:name` route and use `res.render(...)` to render the result.

Comment: Is it an option to access the lessons using `/lessons/lesson01/` (with trailing slash)? That would solve your problem instantly I think (and unless you use `strict routing` with Express, you don't have to change your route handler).

Comment: @robertklep can you explain ? I didn't mention that  was using a middleware to cut the slashes at the end of the url. I'll add it to the question.

Comment: The problem is the base directory from which images are location: the base dir of `/lesson/lesson01` (without slash) is `/lesson/`. If there *was* a trailing slash, the base dir for the image would be `/lesson/lesson01/`, and that's right where the image file is located (so you can use the static middleware). But that's not going to work if you're stripping slashes, obviously :)

Comment: @robertklep That indeed solved the problem. I was hoping to use canonical urls without the slashes at the end. Can you think of any workaround ?

Comment: Two workarounds I can think of: fix the image paths in your md files (either after rendering to HTML, or on disk), or at server startup use `fs.readdir()` to find all `lessonXX` directories and install a static middleware for each separately.

Comment: Another workaround: create a handler to catch requests for the images and handle reading the image file and sending the response yourself.