# Node Express sendFile requiring ending slash

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using the following `get`:

```
app.get("/:project/*", auth, function (req, res) {
```

Then parsing against a config file to load a directory dynamically:

```
var path = req.params[0] ? req.params[0] : "index.html";
res.sendfile( path, { root: "./builds/" + config[req.params.project].dir + "/dist/" } );
```

Which works great, only problem is that it requires my urls to end with a "/" if I'm going to the default (`index.html`). For example, I have to use `http://server.com/some_project/` and if the trailing slash isn't there it throws a `Cannot GET /some_project` error. Curious if there's a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get("/:project/?*", ...)
```

Add the question mark. That should allow you to do with or without the trailing slash.

Comment: Tried adding the `?` and now it doesn't seem to load anything on the route, just hangs there until it times out.

Comment: Can you share some info? Url you tried and maybe the stack trace?

Comment: It's not even hitting the `app.get("/:project/?*", ...)`. I console log'd right inside and nothing. The URL is on a private server but it's just as stated in the original question, nothing special.

Comment: Looks like I may be best implementing a forced trailing slash, something like (the reverse of) this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13443359/957500 with conditions to handle files in the req.params