# Node.js redirect with/without trailing slash

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect

I have a javascript that does different things depending on the URL.
for that to work, i need to have consistent URIs.

for example, i need users to always be on `www.site.com/users/bob/` instead of `www.site.com/users/bob`

node unfortunately doesn't support that, as it seems.

i tried redirecting with

```
router.get('/:user', function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/users/' + req.params.user' + '/');
});
```

but it just results in a redirect loop, as the URL with and without slash seem to be treated as the same.

how can i do this?
thanks!

## edit:

i want to route from WITHOUT slash to WITH slash.
the answers in the other question address the other way around.
i can't .substr(-1) my URLs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect all trailing slashes gloablly in express](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442377/redirect-all-trailing-slashes-gloablly-in-express)

Comment: nope, officer. this one is the other way

Comment: You can use the same method, but do the inverse... Check if there is a trailing slash, if not, redirect by adding a trailing slash.

Comment: well this is EXACTLY what i said didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get this by using third-party library which is called [express-slash](https://github.com/ericf/express-slash) . All you need to do is,

First, install the library

```
$ npm install express-slash
```

And, add these to your app.js.

```
var slash   = require('express-slash');

app.use(slash()); // set slash middleware
```

Then, this is your router.

```
router.get('/:user/', function(req, res) {
    // do your stuff
});
```

Hope it will be useful for you.

Comment: i thought more of a short snippet without the need for an external middleware, but this will have to do. thanks!

Answer (score 31):

In case someone else is looking for a quick zero dependency solution, this worked fine for me:

```
app.get('/:page', function(req, res){
  // Redirect if no slash at the end
  if (!req.url.endsWith('/')) {
    res.redirect(301, req.url + '/')
  }

  // Normal response goes here
});
```

Comment: This is obviously the better answer and should be marked correct instead. People shouldn't always rely on dependencies for the smallest things.

Comment: Are you considering queries after path?

Comment: @AlexanderFuchs In my opinion the accepted answer solves the problem more completely as it considers redirect loops and query strings.  I hate 2 line snippet libraries too, but there are no sub-dependencies and there's more going on here if you check out the [github source](https://github.com/ericf/express-slash/blob/master/index.js)  Both methods (snippets and libraries) have their pros and cons and I guess it all depends on what the programmer requires.

Comment: This is a good solution for pages that do not accept URL params, at least. ETA: or it would be, except in a subapplication you can register as `app.use("/path/to/sub/", sub)` then when the user visits `/path/to/sub` your handler is called with `req.url == "/"`.  I had to check `req.originalUrl` and it might have been easier to just register middleware at a higher level.

Comment: Actually redirecting to `req.url` won't work for subapplications anyway, since the redirect is relative to domain root, not subapplication root.  You need `originalUrl` (or something computed from `baseUrl`) for that as well.

Comment: this will fail when user url has extension in it. ex '/static/js/main.js' => '/static/js/main.js/' .  giving 404

Comment: I agree this should be top answer, but should use originalUrl like @Coderer said as just url will fail in some cases.

Comment: also doesn't support query string parameters... very limited solution

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding this answer as a full solution that redirects non-slash routes to end with a slash.

Firstly, enable a strict router (v4+) to disable the auto normalisation.

```
express.Router({strict: true});
```

Then start your router with a catch-all route which detects if it doesn't end with a slash - and in this case also omits anything with a (.) - so images etc aren't caught.

```
var url = require('url');
router.all(/^[^.]*[^\/]$/, function(req, res) {
    let u = url.parse(req.originalUrl);
    return res.redirect(301, u.pathname + '/' + (u.search || ''));
});
```

This works with query string parameters etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [jncraton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40430493/1081447), but only append slashes to directories..

```
const path = require('path')

app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    if (!req.url.endsWith('/') && !path.extname(req.url)) {
        res.redirect(301, req.url + '/')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set this `use` after the 'express.static' `use` and before other `use` methods.

This code removes the slash from the end of path if it exists, and redirects to the new URL.

If you what to add a slash you can change it so that it adds a slash if the original path *doesn't* have one.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    let url = parseURL(req.url),
        pathname = url.pathname,
        search = url.search || '',
        hasSlash = pathname.charAt(pathname.length - 1) === '/';

    if (hasSlash && pathname !== '/') {
        // remove slash
        pathname = pathname.slice(0, -1);
        // redirect to truest url
        res.redirect(301, pathname + search);
    } else {
        return next();
    }
});
```

Comment: Wait, what, `charAt`? That’s something you would only find in a museum.