# Error in serving a specific file using express.static

Tags: node.js, angular, express, server, routes

I am using a node server to serve files and also build an API for an app, which also uses Angular 4. I am facing trouble serving a specific file from the node_modules folder. The file should be at url http://localhost/node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css.
But the address is automatically redirected to the URL with a trailing slash, and gives the response 'Cannot GET /node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css/'.

Other files in the same directory are being served without any problem. Also, renaming this file cures this problem. Here is the code:

```
var express = require('express'),
  mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
  routes = require('./server/routes.js'),
  fs = require('fs'),
  path = require('path');

var app = express();

mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1");

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use("/", express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
app.use("/node_modules", express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')));
routes(app); //API
app.listen(80);
console.log("Listening");
```

Comment: Have you tried `app.use( express.static(__dirname + '/dist') ); ` ?

Comment: @echonax The file is actually in /node_modules/, so the statement `app.use("/node_modules", express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')));` must have been responsible for that. I tried changing that to `__dirname + '/node_modules'`, but it gives the same error.

Comment: No I meant the line above that

Comment: @echonax Yep, I tried changing that too. But it still won't work.

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442377/redirect-all-trailing-slashes-globally-in-express?

Comment: @echonax That did work! But what must be causing this? Should I report an issue?

Comment: I don't know :-) but let's mark this as a dupe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect all trailing slashes globally in express](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442377/redirect-all-trailing-slashes-globally-in-express)