# Express adds trailing slash

Tags: node.js

I have tried several ways of serving up a static directory. Here is a simple way I am doing this.

```
var app = express();

app.all('*', express.static('./public'));

module.exports = app;

// run the server
http.createServer(app).listen(8080);
```

I have several other configurations like:

```
app.use('/', express.static('./public'));
```

There is an index.html file in the public directory that gets served up fine. The only thing in the HTML file is a request for a JavaScript file. When that request gets made, express throws a 301 redirect, and adds a trailing slash.

Here is the HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/dist/bundle.js"></script>
```

Here is the network request.

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I had this problem because of some bug which I had fixed but it kept recurring because of the browser cache. Try disabling the browser cache before reloading.

Answer (score 7):

You can enable strict route mode and use a route middleware (https://stackoverflow.com/a/15773824/781251)

http://expressjs.com/en/api.html

```
const router = express.Router({ strict: true })
```

Comment: Would this only work with using the express.Router class or can this also be set as an option using the shorthand app.get() declaration?

Answer (score 1):

This means the asset can't be found. It renders a 404 response.