# Wildcard express route

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using express to serve my angular bundle:

```
const server = express();
server.use('/', signupPost);
server.use('/', loginPost);
server.use('/', facebookAuthGet);
server.use('/', googleAuthGet);
server.use('/', storePatch);

// expose the other assets for the html to reference
server.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, dirPrefix, 'frontend')));
// serve our bundle
server.use('*', express.static(path.join(__dirname, dirPrefix, 'frontend/index.html')));

server.listen(port, () => {
  logger.info(`Server started at ${process.env.DOMAIN}`);
});
```

This works well and fine for all routes EXCEPT for those ending in a trailing slash. E.g. `/test` would hit the bundle (to be handled by the SPA), but `/test/` does not and returns

> Cannot GET /test/

I've tried to match `*/*`, `**` and `*/` without success. How can I get express to treat `/test/` the same as `/test`?

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/48362260/13211263

Comment: Thanks, that lead me to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15773824/10988271 which was the solution for me.