# CSS and JS not loading with trailing slash in URL

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was building a Node.js server locally that would listen at `localhost:8080`. The landing page is an html file named `index.html`. If I type `localhost:8080/index.html`, the HTML, along with the CSS file (`main.css`) and JavaScript (`main.js`) located in the same folder as `index.html` will load just fine. But if I typed the same URL with a trailing slash, as `localhost:8080/index.html/`, it only loads the html, not the CSS or JS. I tried going into the HTML page source in Chrome and clicking on the css file in there, and it seems to look for a `localhost:8080/index.html/main.css` file (as seen from the address bar of the browser), which obviously doesn't exist. It appears that it's assuming `index.html` to be a directory for some reason. Any help would be great.

Edit:
The part of the server that deals with routing looks like this (I'm just starting out, and I'm trying to route without using Express.js):

```
const http = require("http");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const url = require("url");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    function writeContentType(headerText) {
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", headerText);
    }
    let requestedPath = url.parse(request.url, true).pathname;
    requestedPath = requestedPath.replace(/^\/+|\/+$/g, "");
    requestedPath = requestedPath.replace(/\//g, "\\");
    requestedPath = "\\" + requestedPath;
    if (requestedPath === "\\") requestedPath = "\\index.html";
    if (!fs.existsSync(__dirname + requestedPath)) {
        console.log("file does not exist, requested path is " + __dirname + requestedPath);
        writeContentType("text/html");
        response.write("<h1>Error 404</h1><h2>Page not found</h2>");
        response.end();
    } else {
        let responseFile = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + requestedPath, function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
        if (responseFile) {
            let fileExtension = path.extname(requestedPath);
            switch(fileExtension) {
                case ".html" : writeContentType("text/html"); break;
                case ".css" : writeContentType("text/css"); break;
                case ".js" : writeContentType("text/javascript"); break;
                case ".svg" : writeContentType("image/svg+xml"); break;
                case ".jpg" :
                case ".jpeg" : writeContentType("image/jpeg"); break;
            }
            response.end(responseFile);
        }
    }
}).listen(8080);
```

The idea was to strip all slashes at the beginning and end of `requestedPath`, replace any slashes on the inside with backslashes because my filesystem is in windows, and then add a backslash at the beginning, and then look for the file in the filesystem.
I might be going against a lot of best practices here, I'm just starting out.

Comment: can you show us the code on how you create a server?

Comment: I've added the server code too now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Wherever you referring the JS and CSS files, use a '/' in front so that it always takes searches in root directory for the files. For example,

   href="/styles.css"
2. Always to use express.static to serve static files

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior, when you hit `localhost:8080/` you expect to be served with index.html

So when you add trailing slash it assumes it is a directory and looks for your files there.

Try to use npm package [express-slash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-slash) or make custom middleware such as:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.path.substr(-1) == '/' && req.path.length > 1) {
       const query = req.url.slice(req.path.length);
       res.redirect(301, req.path.slice(0, -1) + query);
    } else {
       next();
    }
});
```

A similar problem can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442377/redirect-all-trailing-slashes-globally-in-express/35927027)