# RegExp objects made by regular expression literals share a single instance?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>chap07</title>
    <script>
    function make_a_matcher(){
        return /a/gi;
    }

    var x = make_a_matcher();
    var y = make_a_matcher();

    x.lastIndex = 10;

    document.writeln('<div>x.global : '+x.global+'<div>');
    document.writeln('<div>x.ignoreCase : '+x.ignoreCase+'<div>');
    document.writeln('<div>x.lastIndex : '+x.lastIndex+'<div>');
    document.writeln('<div>x.multiline : '+x.multiline+'<div>');
    document.writeln('<div>x.source : '+x.source+'<div>');

    document.writeln('<div>y.global : '+y.global+'<div>');
    document.writeln('<div>y.ignoreCase : '+y.ignoreCase+'<div>');
    document.writeln('<div>y.lastIndex : '+y.lastIndex+'<div>');
    document.writeln('<div>y.multiline : '+y.multiline+'<div>');
    document.writeln('<div>y.source : '+y.source+'<div>');
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm studying JavaScript with "JavaScript The Good Parts" written by Douglas Crockford.
He described that RegExp objects made by regular expression literals share a single instance and above example.

The result in the book is `y.lastIndex : 10`. But my result is `y.lastIndex : 0`.

I would appreciated if you tell me the exact reason of this diffrent result.

Comment: I think Crockford's information is out of date. In modern browsers you'll get separate instances. (Try _console.log (x===y)_)

Comment: Are you sure he's not talking about the `RegExp` function object, which does have some properties that are shared among all regex instances?

Answer (score 0):

Crockford's info is not correct (or not current) and any simple test will verify that you get a new and different object each time you call your function.

If you want them to return the same object, you can do this:

```
var make_a_matcher = (function() {
    var regex = /a/gi;
    return function() {
        return regex;
    }
})();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/FaDwP/

Answer (score 0):

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814009/how-often-does-javascript-recompile-regex-literals-in-functions) and it's answers. In particular one of the answers references the [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) spec, §7.8.5 Regular Expression Literals, which states that:

> A regular expression literal is an input element that is converted to a RegExp object (see 15.10) each time the literal is evaluated.

So each time the function make_a_matcher is called a new regexp object is created. It seems Mr Crockford's book might be out of date if it states otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this,

```
function make_a_matcher(){
  return /a/gi;
}

var x = make_a_matcher();
var y = make_a_matcher();
```

you are creating separate instances. It's the same as:

```
function make_a_matcher(){
  return new RegExp('a', 'gi');
}
```

If you create the instance before you create `make_a_matcher()`, it should work,

```
var agi = /a/gi;
function make_a_matcher(){
  return agi;
}
```

although there would be no need since you could just use that variable.

Answer (score 0):

In my computer, y is also equal to 0;
Because make_a_matcher function return an object called RegExp object, and x, y are different instances of RegExp object, which means that x, y are separate!

```
function make_a_matcher() {
return /a/gi;
}
var x = make_a_matcher();
var y = make_a_matcher();
x.lastIndex = 10;
console.log(y.lastIndex);
```

[image]

In the follow picture we can see that x, y are different instances of RegExp, but not equal.
[image]